# Representation of sigma complete Boolean algebras

Tags: representation-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

In Terrence Tao's article [245B notes 4: The Stone and Loomis-Sikorski representation theorems](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/245b-notes-1-the-stone-and-loomis-sikorski-representation-theorems-optional/) he gives a proof that not each sigma-complete Boolean algebra can be realized as a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra of sets. I have what appears to be a proof to the contrary, and I (and my colleagues) cannot find the error.

- Every $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra is a Boolean algebra
- Every Boolean algebra admits a representation as a Boolean algebra of sets (Stone)
- An isomorphism of Boolean algebras is an order isomorphism
- An order isomorphism preserves all meets and joins present in its domain
- Hence, a Boolean algebra isomorphism preserves all meets and joins in its domain
- Therefore every if $f:B\to C$ is a Boolean algebra isomorphism and $B$ is $\sigma$-complete, $C$ is $\sigma$-complete and $f$ preserves countable joins and meets
- Every $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra admits a representation as a Boolean algebra of sets

What went wrong?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114597/kappa-distributivity-and-stones-representation-theorem

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that countable joins and meets in a Boolean algebra of sets need not be unions and intersections.  So, the last step is wrong: an isomorphism from your Boolean algebra $B$ to an algebra of sets $C$ need not be a representation of $B$ as a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra, since it maps countable joins and meets in $B$ to countable joins and meets in $C$, which are not necessarily unions and intersections of sets.

Comment: Oh! That is a subtle point! Thank you!